# json_encode() excluding UTF-8 encoded string from output

Tags: php, json, cakephp, utf-8

I'm using CakePHP to output an array that contains several UTF-8 encoded strings. I have a layout set up for the output (it's a REST API method):

```
<?php.
  header("Pragma: no-cache");.
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");.
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');.
  header("X-JSON: ".$content_for_layout);.
  echo $content_for_layout;.
?>
```

This is my view:

```
<?php echo json_encode($items); ?>
```

My database table where I get the data is encoded in utf-8. But when I output the data if one of its elements has special characters like à, á, etc, the string will be set to null in the JSON array. How can I properly output my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your database connection is not set to utf-8, which is the most important part. So add `'encoding' => 'utf8'` to the database configuration in your `app/config/database.php`, for example:

```
    'default' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'YOURHOST',
        'login'    => 'YOURLOGIN',
        'password' => 'YOURPASS',
        'database' => 'YOURDB',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    ),
```

If you don't set the encoding in the connection, a "default" encoding will be used. The default is likely not utf8.

Comment: Let me check, though there is a problem, some tables are set to latin1 and others to utf8, won't this generate some inconsistency? (don't judge me :( I didn't set up the DB or the site)

Comment: Just checked and the encoding is set to utf-8, any difference with utf8?

Comment: @8vius MySQL calls it "utf8", not "utf-8". The application has been cruising along with broken encoding settings so far...

Comment: There won't be any inconsistency; MySQL will return all text in the connection encoding. The `latin1` text will also be returned in UTF-8. If this causes display errors check that you have set `App.encoding` to utf-8 in `config/core.php`.

Comment: It's set and I am getting display errors, like mentioned in the comments to @deceze's answer.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since it directly let me to the issue, thanks @Joni

Answer (score 1):

That most likely means your data is *not* encoded in UTF-8, most likely because the database *connection* is not set to UTF-8 and you're actually receiving the data in latin1 on the PHP side. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for a rundown of all gotchas.

Comment: My database table is set to utf8_general_ci, how can I do the proper setup for CakePHP? Though I really shouldn't because I might break the entire site (I didn't develop it, I'm just adding an API method)

Comment: @Joni just provided the answer. If you cannot change that default though (indeed, if it has been used without a proper connection setting so far your data will screw up royally if you change it), you'll have to convert the encoding of the strings manually as shown in the other answers. Why that doesn't work for you I don't know. Show us a `bin2hex($string)` of one of the strings so we can see what encoding they seem to be in.

Comment: Just did the change that @Joni said, now I get the string with the encoding of the characters like \u00f3, and in the view it's broken and shows stuff like Ã³

Comment: @8vius Yup, because the data in the database is already garbage. Why is explained in detail in my linked article... :)

Comment: In the database, if I look at it in phpMyAdmin it displays properly with the special characters and all.

Comment: ...because the phpMyAdmin connection encoding is probably set to latin1 as well...? Try inserting or retrieving a character not in the latin1 charset, like "漢字".

Comment: `json_encode` is supposed to return `\u00f3` for ó. If you want that not happen there's a flag you can set, `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. As to Ã³, are you setting the content type header manually instead of using the `HtmlHelper::charset` function? Make sure that you set the charset to utf-8 in the Content-Type header

Comment: @8vius Good luck sorting that out. :-3 The best thing obviously is to convert the whole database to proper UTF-8 by dumping it as "latin1", then reimporting it properly as utf8.

Comment: Where do I set the flag? Yes the app is using the HtmlHelper::charset function, bear in my mind this is code I inherited, not my own, so navigating it is quit troublesome.

Comment: @8vius He means a flag for the `json_encode` function. It's not a Cake thing.

Comment: Yeah I got that, @deceze, thank you. I believe we're extending this too much, so thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = json_encode( array_map( function($text){ return is_string($text) ? utf8_encode($text) : $text; }, $items) )
echo $items;
```

Comment: Same error, the data from the database is alreadt utf-8 encoded.